# How to schedule commands to run in background in Azkaban

Tags: bash, background, command, azkaban

In bash script, I can append & at the end of the command to make it run in the background such as:

```
top &
```

However, when I put that in a Azkaban job, such as:

```
type=command
command=top &
```

It will give the error message as:

```
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR - invalid option or syntax: &
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR - top usage: top
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-a | -d | -e | -c ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-F | -f]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-h]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-i ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-l ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-ncols ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-o ] [-O ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-R | -r]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-S]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-s ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-n ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-stats ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-pid ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start INFO - Process completed unsuccessfully in 0 seconds.
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-user ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-U ]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR -       [-u]
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR - 
29-04-2015 23:53:08 PDT start ERROR - Job run failed!
```

I tried to escape & to write the command as "top \&", but it would still report the same error. I googled for hours and couldn't find a solution, does anyone know how to run commands in the background with Azkaban?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, Azkaban executes the commands directly via OS calls, not through a shell - however, the `&` syntax is only understood by Bash itself. Try placing your command inside a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
top &
```

and schedule

```
bash -c "your_script.sh"
```

to be run instead, or execute

```
bash -c "top &"
```

directly.

By the way, `top` won't run in the background without setting up a dumb terminal first. This is addressed e.g. [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/304470/problems-with-cron-script-and-term-definition-using-top-command).

Comment: Vadim, I accepted your answer, but since I don't have enough reputations, I cannot upvote your answer, I am really sorry... :-(